# How do I redirect traffic from a legacy category URL to a new category URL?

Tags: redirect, server, apache

Within Craft, I am renaming the top-level entry URL format for a section from `legacy-subdirectory/{slug}` to `new-subdirectory/{slug}`. How do I redirect traffic from the legacy URL to the new format within Craft?

I am aware that I may use the rewrite rule within `.htaccess` in exchange for a slight performance hit:

```
    RewriteRule ^legacy-subdirectory/(.*)$ /new-subdirectory/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I would prefer handling this within Craft. As there is only one slug in which I need the redirect, I would prefer handling this without plug-ins.

Comment: I don't think it could be done without a plugin. Craft's routing can handle wildcards on the way in, but not on the way out. At the very least, you'd need to write your own Controller action to handle the wildcard.

Comment: It should be noted that ``.htaccess`` is going to be much faster than going through Craft/PHP because Apache already knows about the redirect before it passes it off to PHP. If you want speed up your site further, ditch your ``.htaccess`` and move whatever is in there  to your vhost configuration and set [``AllowOverride``](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) to ``None`` in the server's main config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Craft has a [twig redirect tag](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/redirect).

You should be able to create a "redirect" template that handles redirects based on {slug} and/or url segments and then use Craft routes to direct "legacy-subdirectory" requests to your redirect template. I have not tested this.

Comment: I stand corrected... this is exactly how you'd do it without a plugin!

Answer (score 7):

There are a few plugins which can handle this, but **Retour** is the newest and shiniest!

> https://github.com/nystudio107/retour

It's from the same developer as SEOmatic... he puts a lot of love & attention into his plugins, so you know it's safe to rely on.